# Nothing happens when I configure RoboGuice

Tags: android, guice, roboguice

I am new to RoboGuice and I am trying to set up my activity to use DI. However, nothing happens when I attempt to use it. I only get a blank black window with no content and no logging in my Activity.onCreate() method after I call "super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);"

See these 2 snippets of code:

```
public class ClikClokActivity extends RoboActivity{
@Inject 
private TileAdapter tileAdapter;
@Inject
private GameLogicService gameLogicService;  
@Inject
private GridOperationQueue gridOperationQueue;
private GridView gridView;
@Inject
private Handler handler;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.v(this.getClass().toString(), "Entering onCreate");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.v(this.getClass().toString(), "Never logs this with RoboGuice");
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setNumColumns(Constants.GRID_WIDTH);
    gridView.setAdapter(tileAdapter);

    Log.v(this.getClass().toString(), "GridView initialized");

    gridOperationQueue.start();

    Log.v(this.getClass().toString(), "Completed onCreate");
}
```

and

```
public class ClikClokApplication extends RoboApplication{

@Override
protected void addApplicationModules(List<Module> modules) {
    modules.add(new ClikClokModule());
}
```

}

and

public class ClikClokModule extends AbstractAndroidModule {

```
@Override
protected void configure() {

}
```

}

and

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.clikclok"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">


<application android:name="com.clikclok.ClikClokApplication" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".ClikClokActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

If you look at the above code, I never get the second logging. However, if I was to extend from Activity instead and remove the android:name="com.clikclok.ClikClokApplication" attribute from my manifest then I do get the second logging (albeit fails with NullPointers as there is no initialization performed).

So what may be happening in super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); that is causing my application not to work?

Thanks

**Update from the above:**

I've spent quite a bit of time investigating this and using Eclipse's debugger can now see where my code seems to hang within RoboGuice.

The following code is from the InjectorImpl class:

```
public void injectMembers(Object instance) {
// Reaches here but...
MembersInjector membersInjector = getMembersInjector(instance.getClass());
// ....this comment is never reached
membersInjector.injectMembers(instance);
```

}

So I dug into the Guice 3.0 code using my debugger and into the FailableCache class:

```
public V get(K key, Errors errors) throws ErrorsException {
// Reaches here....
Object resultOrError = delegate.get(key);
// ...but not here
if (resultOrError instanceof Errors) {
  errors.merge((Errors) resultOrError);
  throw errors.toException();
} else {
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // create returned a non-error result, so this is safe
  V result = (V) resultOrError;
  return result;
}
```

}

How could this be that it just hangs while retrieving a key from a map? I'm not familiar enough with the code and it is quite confusing to troubleshoot.
Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Seems like the only way it could not log the second line is if your app crashed between log 1 and log 2.  Are there any errors in your logs?

Comment: Absolutely nothing in the logs. That is why I am totally lost here

Comment: Also, make sure you are doing everything according to your roboguice version. In roboguice2.0 you don't need (cannot) use the RoboApplication class anymore.. Instead you need to create a roboguice.xml file in your res/values folder. See the upgrading instructions: http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/UpgradingTo20

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some bindings in your configure method.

You can also try to inject your grid view like this
    @InjectView(R.id.gridview)
    GridView gridView;

I hope this will help you.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by me attempting to inject my Activity class into a service class.

So I was attempting to @Inject an instance of "ClikClokActivity" instead of "Activity".

Once I removed this injection attempt, everything worked fine. Not sure if this exposes some other issue with RoboGuice or Guice itself.